# CSS Font Rendering on Windows ISSUE

Tags: css, font-face

Normally i never get this problem, but this time, i really don't know what was going on... Hope someone can help me.

I did look lots of tutorials and hacks to fix the font render problems in Chrome but with no success.

This is my website:
http://server.developweb.com.br/site/

The font is Helvetica, but i did try with Open Sans and got same problem.

The font was rendered like if was low resolution... cant use antaliases css hacks... it do not work...

What it can be?

Ps. The problem doesn`t shows up in MacOSX. Just on Windows...

Comment: Some fonts do that, I had simmilar problem... I have resolved it by using different font. Problem is probably somewhere in chrome's graphic core, you probably won't get over it. try using `    text-shadow: .1px .1px .1px white;`, but I tried it in chrome through developers console, but I dont think it helped too much. But if it will be ok for you, just dont forget to target this shadow only for chrome - webkit core

Comment: Thanks.. i`ll try it and see what happens... i back soon to say what i think of solution...